# proper way to add a record and notify activity using room and mvvm

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room, android-mvvm

I am learning android mvvm structure and I have a doubt while implementing it. I was inserting a user object in database using room. But, I don't know how to notify the activity after inserting has done successfully.

I have tried to implement it. But, It did not work. Let me show my code.

**RegisterActivity**

```
       public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityRegisterBinding activityRegisterBinding;
    RegisterViewModel registerViewModel;
    private final CompositeDisposable mDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initDataBinding();
        onUserRegistered();

    }

    private void initDataBinding() {
        activityRegisterBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_register);

        RegisterViewModelFactory registerViewModelFactory = Injection.provideRegisterViewModelFactory(this);
        registerViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,registerViewModelFactory).get(RegisterViewModel.class);
        activityRegisterBinding.setRegisterViewModel(registerViewModel);
    }

    private void onUserRegistered() {

        findViewById(R.id.register_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDisposable.add(registerViewModel.onClickedSignUp()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new Action() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() throws Exception {
                                Log.e("Success!!!","added a record");
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"success",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                onBackPressed();
                            }
                        }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                                Log.e("Unable to add a record", throwable.toString());
                                throwable.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mDisposable.dispose();
    }
}
```

**RegisterViewModel**

```
public class RegisterViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public ObservableField<String> name;
    public ObservableField<String> password;
    private UserDataSource userDataSource;

    RegisterViewModel(UserDataSource userDataSource){
        name=new ObservableField<>("");
        password=new ObservableField<>("");
        this.userDataSource=userDataSource;
   }

    public TextWatcher nameWatcher=new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

       }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(!name.get().equals(s.toString())){
                name.set(s.toString());
           }
       }
   };

    public TextWatcher passwordWatcher=new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(!password.get().equals(s.toString())){
            password.set(s.toString());
            }
        }
    };

    public Completable onClickedSignUp() {

        isLoading.setValue(true);

        if (name != null)
            Log.e("name", name.get());

       if (password != null)
           Log.e("pass", String.valueOf(password.get()));


       return Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
            @Override
            public void run() throws Exception {
                Log.e("final name",name.get());
                User user=new User(0,name.get(),0,0);
                userDataSource.insertOrUpdateUser(user);
           }
       });
    }
}
```

I am getting proper values of name and password in the log printed from view model, but the record is not added on click event on button, also it does not notify the activity about success or failure. what to do in that case?

Please guide me, as I am new to mvvm and learning it.

Comment: is your question regarding how to notify when data is inserted or why the log is being displayed before button click?

Comment: both. But, major question is how to notify activity only after data is inserted.

Comment: The question is edited. Please see the edited question. (code of the register activity is modified).

Comment: Issue is solved when I removed onclick from xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return of the insert method in the Data Access Object interface is void. You do not get a call back when the data is inserted. You can perform the task you want to perform just after calling the insert method

Also I would advise you to dispose of the disposables you have added in mDisposable in `onDestroy` method of the activity

Comment: thanx for reminding me about disposing the disposable in the on destroy.

Comment: But, I did not understand how to show a toast or  anything (something related to UI) after button click in activity. (not in view model).

Comment: u need to add a click listener to the button. Have a look at this link
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

U can add toast, navigate to another activity or perform any other task you need in the `onClick()` call back

Comment: you did not understood what I am saying. I am saying that, How to notify view (here, activity) using mvvm structure and using RxJava. after completing the insert task performed in the view model.

Comment: Using RxJava I would suggest to use PublishSubject. It acts as a pipe, where you enter data from one side and listen from the other side.

However, using MutableLiveData would be a better fix here. It is coupled with the lifecycle of the activity, so even if your activity is destroyed, there wont be any leaks

Comment: Please refer to these links

https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-livedata-1ce4ab3c0466

https://medium.com/@taman.neupane/basic-example-of-livedata-and-viewmodel-14d5af922d0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168614/discussion-between-aditya-and-riddhi).